# How to "globally" blacklist a user from using my discord bot?

Tags: discord.js

**[EDIT] This has been fixed!**

I just needed to use `client.users.cache.get(args[0])`

---

In itself, it works, except the part where I can just send a user ID, which then blacklists the user.
As long as the member is in the server where the command is ran, it works. Coded in DJS and Mongoose

````
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

module.exports = {
    name: "blacklist",
    aliases: ["b", "block"],
    cooldown: 5000,
    description: "Blocks a user from using Hexagon!",
    devOnly: true,
    category: "Developer",
    usage: "blacklist <user> [reason]",

    async run(client, message, args) {
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply('`[❌]` Incorrect Syntax: Missing Argument')

        const mentionedUser = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || client.users.cache.fetch(args[0]);
        if(!mentionedUser) return message.reply('`[❌]` Incorrect Syntax: Provided User does not exist!')

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) reason = "Reason not specified."

        let profile = blacklistedUsers.findOne({userID: mentionedUser.user.id})
        
        if(profile) return message.reply('`[❌]` Error: Mentioned User is already blacklisted!')

        profile = await new blacklistedUsers({
            userID: mentionedUser.user.id,
            reason
        }).save();
        message.channel.send(`\`❌\` ${mentionedUser.user.tag} was blacklisted!`)
    }
}```

I just want to be able to run "blacklist <userID> [reason]" with the userID being an ID that is not a server member, but rather a user in the bot's cache.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this, is in your handler, use a `string.includes` to check blacklisted ids (hopefully separated by commas or such) and check if any match.

```js
//for example:
let tableExample; //mongoose table I use for the object, change to your needs

if (tableExample.blacklistedIDs.includes(message.author.id)) return;

//obviously I use blacklistedIDs, change this to your needs also
```

This method would check the database for any id and if it matches a user's id when running the command it will cancel.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the main issue. I want to be able to blacklist users without them being in the server the command is run in.

Comment: Yeah, its still just as easy, you simply need the user id and add it to the blacklistedIDs field - this code is for when a blacklisted user **runs** any command, you need to put it in your handler.

Comment: But then I would need to add the ID manually, since the command only works, when the user is in the server

Comment: how else were you planning on adding a blacklisted id? surely the !blacklist command adds the id to a database? - aswell as this, using the method above, the user will **never** be able to use commands in **any** server.

Comment: !blacklist only works when the user is in the server, but I want to blacklist users that are not in the same server as me, but share a server with my bot

Comment: just use an OR operator for the id if there is no mentioned user - problem solved